# PHP error shows only once, disappear when refreshed

Tags: php, error-handling, php-ini

I am in a peculiar problem with PHP error. I set   `error_reporting = E_ALL` , `display_errors = On` and `display_startup_errors = On`   in php.ini file . I get an error for only once.  That means I have an error in my script if I execute the script through the browser it shows the error normally. But If I refresh the page, the error disappears.

How can I get rid of this situation ??

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are they related to sessions?

Comment: it may be helpful to know what exactly the error is. if it's something about the session for example, that could explain why it happens only once...

Comment: Sorry.... My magic ball isn't working today. Otherwise i could have given the answer without your effort to post the code.

Comment: put ob_start() in your page...........

Comment: @Foysal, I have the same problem and I believe it isnt wrong in the code, but some server configuration causing it.

Comment: I found what caused my log file disappeared. It was Winscps feature "Keep remote directory up to date" that kept deleting the log file :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have something you are setting in the SESSION scope that isn't present on first load, and is each subsequent load.  We need more detail to be sure.  Can you show your code?

Comment: here is the error 
Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_VARIABLE in L:\PHP\xampp\htdocs\puran\object\private.php on line 22
I got this error if I restart apache, then if I refresh the page the error disappears.

Comment: @Foysal, OK, but we still need to see the code that's creating the error, in this case the code of **private.php**

Comment: here is my code

private class paper
{
 function paste()
 {
  echo 'mouse';
 }
}


$a = new paper();
$a->paste();